# How to know when a pynput Listener is stopped?

Tags: python, attributes, listener, daemon, pynput

I didn't found the attribute isrunning/isactive of the daemon in [the doc](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html).

```
from pynput import mouse, keyboard
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    print(x, y , pressed)

def on_press(key):
    print(key, 'pressed')
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        return False

def on_release(key):
    print(key, 'released')

keyboard_listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release)
mouse_listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)
mouse_listener.isac
#keyboard_listener.start()
#mouse_listener.start()
print("yolo")

while 1:
    sleep(5)
    print(keyboard_listener)
```

I know there is one because I see it on the print:

```
<Listener(Thread-8, started daemon 14832)>
Key.esc pressed
<Listener(Thread-8, stopped daemon 14832)>
```

So my question is what is the attribute of a Listener in the pynput library that I can check to know if the program is running or not ?

I want to do this

```
while 1:
    if keyboard_listener.THEATTRIBUTEIMLOOKINGFOR:
        do_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

[Good doc](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pynput/latest/pynput.pdf)

The attribute is named running.

So keyboard_listener.running will return me True or False